Probability of picking red card

Take a shuffled deck of $52$ playing cards and throw the first $10$ cards in the bin. What is the probability that the new top card is red?

Since we start off with a deck consisting of $52$ cards with $26$ reds and $26$ blacks, can we say the probability of picking a red card once $10$ cards are removed is just $\frac{26}{42}$?
Is my intuitive answer valid?

You are assuming that the first 10 cards are all black, which is clearly wrong.

The intuitive-reasoning answer is this:
Initially, with a deck of 52 playing cards, symmetry says you have a 50% chance of drawing a red card off the top.
If you throw away 10 cards, that process isn't biased towards red or black, so your knowledge of which card remains on top is still symmetric between red and black. Symmetry means you still have a 50% chance of red.  (If you do the complicated arithmetic to compute the actual odds, you can prove this rigorously.)
Here's another way to look at it: if instead of throwing those 10 cards away, you just place all ten at the bottom of the deck, you now still have a well-shuffled deck of 52 cards, and symmetry says that your probability of drawing a red card off the top is 50%.

Thank you! So even if we keep drawing cards without replacement, the probability is still going to be 1/2, is that correct?

Yes. The only thing that could change that is if you broke the perfect symmetry of the situation --- for example, if you looked at any of the cards as you drew them, it would shift your knowledge of what cards remain. It is important that "throw away" means "throw away without looking at them".

Thank you so much for your thorough response!

You might have thrown away 10 red cards or you might have thrown away 10 black cards.  In the first case the probability is 16/42 and in the second it is 26/42. If you threw away 5 red and 5 black, the probability would be 21/42 or 1/2.
The answer is more complicated than your intuition which is often the case with probability.

I agree. This was asked on an online test I took, and the time limit for this question was only 1min 30 secs. It isn't possible to enumerate all the possibilities in a short amount of time. How to use intuition or shortcuts to arrive at a concrete solution for this problem?

@ShsTht By recognizing that the question is equivalent to asking for the probability that the 11th card is red, and then recognizing that this is equivalent to asking for the probability that the 1st card is red.

To do this rigorously, we can perform the following:
$\frac{1}{\binom{52}{10}} \cdot \left( \binom{26}{10}\binom{26}{0} \frac{26-10}{42}  + \binom{26}{9}\binom{26}{1} \frac{26-9}{42} + \cdots +  \binom{26}{1} \binom{26}{9} \frac{26-1}{42} + \binom{26}{0}\binom{26}{10} \frac{26-0}{42} \right) = 0.5$
$\binom{52}{10}$ corresponds to the number of combinations to choose any 10 cards to throw away
$\binom{26}{10}\binom{26}{0}$ corresponds to the number of combinations to choose 10 red cards and 0 blue cards
Then $\frac{(26-10)}{42}$ corresponds to the probability to choose a red card after throwing away 10 cards.
$\binom{26}{9}\binom{26}{1}$ corresponds to the number of combinations to choose 9 red cards and 1 blue cards.
Then $\frac{(26-9)}{42}$ corresponds to the probability to choose a red card after throwing away 10 cards.
Generally $\binom{26}{i}\binom{26}{10-i}$ corresponds to the number of combinations to choose i red cards and 10-i blue cards for $0<= i <= 10$ and $\frac{26-i}{42}$ corresponds to the probability to choose a red card after throwing away 10 cards.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
